# How to tell if you can apply Machine Learning to a project?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am working on a personal project in which I log data of the bike rental service my city has in a MySQL database. A script runs every thirty minutes and logs data for every bike station and the free bikes each one has. Then, in my database I average the availability of each station for each day at that given time making it, as today, an approximate prediction with 2 months of data logging.

I've read a bit on machine learning and I'd like to learn a bit. Would it be possible to train a model with my data and make better predictions with ML in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very likely yes.

The first step is to have some data, and it sounds like you do.  You have a response (free bikes) and some features on which it varies (time, location). You have already applied a basic conditional means model by averaging values over factors. 
You might augment the data you know about locations with some calendar events like holiday or local event flags.

Prepare a data set with one row per observation, and benchmark the accuracy of your current forecasting process for a period of time on a metric like Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE).  Ensure your predictions (averages) for the validation period do not include any of the data within the validation period! 
 Use the data for this period to validate other models you try.

Split off part of the remaining data into a test set, and use the rest for training.  If you have a lot of data, then a common training/test split is 70/30. If the data is small you might go down to 90/10.

Learn one or more machine learning models on the training set, checking performance periodically on the test set to ensure generalization performance is still increasing.  Many training algorithm implementations will manage this for you, and stop automatically when test performance starts to decrease due to overfitting. This a big benefit of machine learning over your current straight average, the ability to learn what generalizes and throw away what does not.

Validate each model by predicting over the validation set, computing the MAPE and compare the MAPE of the model to that of your original process on the same period.  Good luck, and enjoy getting to know machine learning!